# How to get union of key values, and preserve union values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type that looks like this:

```
type g = {
    cat: (Record<"cat", string> | undefined);
    dog: ({ dogSound: string } | Record<"dog", string>);
}

type f = g[keyof g]
```

I'd like to create a union, and get this result:

```
type x = (Record<"cat", string> | undefined) & ({ dogSound: string } | Record<"dog", string>)
```

Essentially I want to get the values:

When I do

```
type g = {
    cat: (Record<"cat", string> | undefined);
    dog: ({ dogSound: string } | Record<"dog", string>);
}

type f = g[keyof g]
```

It produces this:

```
type f = Record<"cat", string> | {
    dogSound: string;
} | Record<"dog", string> | undefined
```

It becomes one big union, and it's not segregated anymore, there are no parenthesis.

Comment: I don't think your expected result is what you actually expect... some parenthesis would help.

Comment: Could you parenthesize your `type x`?  It evaluates to `type x = Record<"cat", string> | Record<"dog", string>` in the IDE; not sure if that's what you really want.

Comment: @Gerrit0  I updated the post with some parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this achieves what I want:

```
type UnionToIntersectionValues<U, K extends keyof U = keyof U> =
    (K extends never
        ? unknown
        : K extends unknown
        ? (k: U[K]) => void
        : never
    ) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never
```